# Using k-means on an image vector

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, k-means

I have a nagging doubt while using k-means on an image vector. I have an RGB image which I have converted into the HSV space. Basically I want to perform k-means on the H vector alone. This is a 214 by 300 vector.

I have two questions:

1.Should I reshape the samples as a 64200*1 vector before I feed it into the kmeans command?

2.How do I find the centre of each cluster(I'm clustering into 4 clusters, hence I need 4 positions each representing the centre of each cluster.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you should reshape your matrix to a `1xN` vector, where `N` corresponds to the number of hue values you are clustering.  Each one is treated as an individual datapoint to be clustered.
2. A large part of k-means is finding the correct cluster centres.  This happens for you, it does not need to be set a priori.  If you want to initialize the clustering with good centres, look into [k-means++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means++), but you do not have to find the cluster centres before running k-means.  To get the computed cluster centres after clustering, you just need to look at the output array provided from the call to k-means.  The signature is as follows:

   double kmeans(InputArray data, int K, InputOutputArray bestLabels, TermCriteria criteria, int attempts, int flags, OutputArray centers=noArray() );

As you can see, the last parameter to the kmeans() call is the a matrix containing the cluster centres.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!..However the size of my centres matrix is N*1(for an N*1 input)...Im looking to get only 4 values(one value for cluster 1,another for cluster2 and so on)...Am I missing something here??

Comment: @Chris...cv::kmeans(channelhue,count,labels,TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1.0),5,KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS,centers);

Comment: And the number of rows in "centers" isn't equal to what you've put for "count"?

Comment: No!!...it is equal to the number of rows of the channelhue matrix

Comment: That's okay, it sounds like you've got it? :)

Comment: @ashwinshanker Great!  Just a heads up since you appear to be new (based on your reputation score), we "vote up" answers that are helpful and correct (the arrow above the number beside an answer), and "accept" the answer that solved our question.  Good luck with k-means!